# Notepad++ split numeric values separated with semi-colons and commas keeping the lines having single pairs intact

Tags: regex, csv, notepad++

I have thousands of record which look like this:

```
35;36,58
36;2
37;5,58,17
```

My goal output is this:

```
35;36
35;58
36;2
37;5
37;58
37;17
```

Is this event possible with some sort of regex?

Comment: Try `^(\d+);(\d+),(.+)` and replace with `$1;$3\n$1;$2` and click *Replace All* until no replacements are made. This way, the lines will be split in a different order though. `35;36,58` -> `35;58`, `35;36`.

Comment: Thank you very much wiktor, this works perfectly

Comment: I improved it to produce the output required in OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^(\d+);(.+),(\d+)
```

And replace with `$1;$2\n$1;$3`. Click <kbd>Replace All</kbd> *repeatedly* until no replacements are made.

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(\d+)` - 1 digits (Group 1)
- `;` - a literal `;`
- `(.+)` - 1+ chars other than linebreak char as many as possible until the last
- `,(\d+)` - comma and Group 2, one or more digits

[image]